# how to allow unamed user in svn authz file?

Tags: authentication, authorization, anonymous, apache-config, svn-config

I have a subversion server running with apache. It authenticates users using LDAP in apache configuration and uses SVN authorizations to limit user access to certain repositories. This works perfectly.

Apache

```
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /srv/svn
SVNListParentPath Off
SVNPathAuthz Off
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Subversion Repository"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPBindDN        # private stuff
AuthLDAPBindPassword  # private stuff
AuthLDAPURL           # private stuff
Require valid-user
AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz
```

Subversion

```
[groups]
soft = me, and, all, other, developpers
```

**Adding anonymous access from one machine**

Now, I have a service I want to setup (rietveld, for code reviews) that needs to have an anonymous access to the repository. As this is a web service, accesses are always done from the same server. Thus I added apache configuration to allow all accesses from this machine. This did not work until I add an additional line in the authorization file to allow read access to all users.

Apache

```
<Limit GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from # private IP address
  Satisfy Any
</Limit>
```

Subversion

```
[Software:/]
@soft = rw
* = r                    # <-- This is the added line
```

For instance, before I add the authorization from a specific IP, all users were authenticated, and thus had a name. Now, some accesses are done without a user name! I found the `-` user name in the apache log files, but the line `- = r` does not work, neither do `anonymous = r`. I'd like not to allow read access to everyone in SVN authorization. How can I do this?

Comment: Note that `Satisfy Any` is critical to make this work (see [II.1.B](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.8.0/subversion/mod_authz_svn/INSTALL)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting this in your authz file:

```
[Software:/]
@soft = rw
$anonymous=r
```